# ASIHTTPRequest and other frameworks with ARC

Tags: json, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest

I am having problems using JSON and ASIHTTPRequest with iOS 5. When I add the frameworks for ASIHTTPRequest and JSON to my project I get many ARC errors. How do I avoid these ARC restrictions with the frameworks while still using ASIHTTPRequest in iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable ARC for certain files with the compile flag `-fno-objc-arc`.
So, go to your target's settings and switch to the tab `Build Phases`. Under `Compile Sources`, you can enter the compile flags for all your source files.